# How can i set amount input field as non-editable and editable i am using angularJS programming language

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Logic is for example from my application front end if i select "A biller" in console showing partial_pay : 'N' in that time payment page amount input field should be non-editable

If select " B biller "   in console showing partial_pay : 'Y' in that time payment page amount input field should be editable.

As of now in my application i am not able using that logic. This is what i wrote in html page

```
<div ng-if="payee.partialPay == 'N'"
     class="fmb-fundtransfer-amount fmb-positon-relative"
     layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <fin-input class="fmb-adaptive-font-currency"
            type="money-currency" flex="70"
            option-array="fundTransfer.common.currencyList"
            on-change="angular.element(this).scope().formatAmountCrn('fundTransfer.common.amount','fundTransfer.common.currency');"
            currency-model="fundTransfer.common.currency"
            base-font-size='22px' adaptive-font flexLreadonly >
    </fin-input>
</div>
```

This part of code from js file mentioned

```
self.partialPay="Y";    
parseRegesterdBillerDetails:function(responsesList)
{
self.partialPay = responsesList[0].partialPay;
console.log("non-editable:::"+self.partialPay);
```

Comment: set attribute ng-readonly to true for that input field tag.

Comment: then what  can i applied instead of ng-if and i applied ng-show that is also not worked

Comment: ya i given to the ng-readonly firstly but not working @Sunny

Comment: Show the code for the `fin-input` directive.

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS V7.3  the `on-change` attribute can be simplified by using the [ng-on directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOn).<sup>[1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#173-eventful-proposal-2018-08-03)</sup>

```
<fin-input class="fmb-adaptive-font-currency"
        type="money-currency" flex="70"
        option-array="fundTransfer.common.currencyList"
        ̶o̶n̶-̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶=̶"̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶.̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶)̶.̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶(̶)̶.̶f̶o̶r̶m̶a̶t̶A̶m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶C̶r̶n̶(̶'̶f̶u̶n̶d̶T̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶e̶r̶.̶c̶o̶m̶m̶o̶n̶.̶a̶m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶'̶,̶'̶f̶u̶n̶d̶T̶r̶a̶n̶s̶f̶e̶r̶.̶c̶o̶m̶m̶o̶n̶.̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶c̶y̶'̶)̶;̶"̶ 
        ng-on-change="formatAmountCrn(fundTransfer.common.amount,fundTransfer.common.currency)"
        currency-model="fundTransfer.common.currency"
        base-font-size='22px' adaptive-font flexLreadonly >
</fin-input>
```

The extra advantage is that the production version of AngularJS (`angular.min.js`) can be used. The `element.scope()` method is disabled in the production version for a significant boost in performance.